# Transform projection with SharpMap

Tags: coordinate-system, sharpmap, web-mercator

I have SharpMap loading a shapefile and displaying the rendered image to a PictureBox.

If I open the shapefile in QGis I can see the SRC:

> +proj=merc +lon_0=100 +lat_ts=-41 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

However, when I tried to convert to Webmercator using SharpMap, the map renders empty. 
This is the code I use to re-project (data is the shapeFile object):

```
    ICoordinateSystem sourceTransform = data.CoordinateSystem;

    ICoordinateSystem webmercator = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;

    CoordinateTransformationFactory ctFac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();

    ICoordinateTransformation transform = ctFac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(sourceTransform, webmercator);

    vectorLayer.CoordinateTransformation = transform;
```

I also tried using different WKT, such as

> PROJCS[""WGS_1984_Web_Mercator"",
>                   GEOGCS[""GCS_WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere"",
>                       DATUM[""WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere"",
>                           SPHEROID[""WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere"", 6378137.0, 0.0]],
>                       PRIMEM[""Greenwich"", 0.0],
>                       UNIT[""Degree"", 0.0174532925199433]],
>                   PROJECTION[""Mercator_1SP""],
>                   PARAMETER[""False_Easting"", 0.0],
>                   PARAMETER[""False_Northing"", 0.0],
>                   PARAMETER[""Central_Meridian"", 0.0],
>                   PARAMETER[""latitude_of_origin"", 0.0],
>                   UNIT[""Meter"", 1.0]]

... but there's no transformation at all.

How can I create this transformation?